# Details of the equivalent of joins in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i understand that mongodb does not support "joins" as one finds in a relational database, however i was not sure exactly what this would mean in specific.

Does this mean that you cannot ask mongodb to do the equivelant of:

```
SELECT p.name, j.title FROM person p, job j where p.p_id = j.j_id
```

or merely that it does not enforce referential integrity for you?

I was also hoping to understand how this related to linking ("joining"?) collections. I beleive that the _id reference for the collection should be used like a F.K., however im not sure whether this would rely on the application providing the relevant code to perform the join, or whether mongodb would support this if queried using its native language

Comment: This [**article**](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/model-data-for-ruby-on-rails/#caching-to-avoid-n-1) may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually in multiple queries. A MongoDB query only operates on one collection, and collection are independent of each other.

Comment: thanks for replyng, would this be like pipelinig through the aggregation framework?

Comment: sorry, on second thought i think i see what you mean. As in manually in the application code, as opposed to manually in multiple MongoDB queries?

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can perform left outer equi-joins on **unsharded** collections in mongodb 3.2 using $lookup.

```
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: <collection to join>,
       localField: <field from the input documents>,
       foreignField: <field from the documents of the "from" collection>,
       as: <output array field>
     }
}
```

See [Mongodb $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) for more information.

However, even if mongodb supports joins, it is non relational database and so you should not perform such joins very frequently in your application. You should prefer embedding such documents.